# How can I remove text form AHBottomNavigation lib in android?

Tags: android

I am using this lib in android for my new app.  But I want to **show only icon**, not text. But I cannot remove text. Also, I don't want to change icon position for selected icon tab. Please give me suggestion how I can do it?

Here the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. I hope it can be helpful for the other. for that reason, i share it.

first change your gradle into

```
**dependencies {
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.0.1'
}**
```

add this line to lib
**bottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_HIDE);**

you can know details from this link.

https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Answer (score 0):

use bottomNavigation.setForceTint(true); its works for me